# Recommendation for long-lasting (eg 1 week) airproof and waterproof plaster?

Tags: dermatology, removal, warts, bandaid-plaster-bandage, waterproof-repellent

I'm attempting the "duct tape" treatment for a wart, which has worked well in the past with a verucca.

http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Warts/Pages/Treatment.aspx#Duct tape

The treatment involves sticking some duct tape over the wart and leaving it for six days, then removing it and rubbing off the dead skin with a pumice stone or similar.

The problem I have is that the wart is on my big toe, and it's proving really difficult to get the duct tape to stay on.  I got some extra adhesive waterproof duct tape, and I strap it on with water-resistant Elastoplast plasters, but it still seems to come loose quite quickly.

What would be perfect, I think, is some strips I can put around the outside, like I'm doing with the elastoplasts, to hold the square of duct tape in place, that are really "hardcore" when it comes to sticking, and are also airproof so they don't let air in under the edges of the duct tape.  For the glue strength I was thinking of steri-strips, which I know have some kind of super strong glue that stays attached to the skin for 5-7 days.  But, I don't think steri-strips are airtight.

Anyone got any suggestions?  thanks, Max

Comment: Have you tried applying several layers of liquid bandage, and re-applying frequently?

Comment: No, until now I didn't even know it existed!  Will investigate, thanks.

Comment: I'm making a leap here, since you have a lot of UK references; Boots has a product called Germolene (Amazon UK has it, as well as others).

Comment: @Dorothy I am in the UK (should have said, sorry) and I do know Germolene but AFAIK it's just an antiseptic cream.  Are you talking about one of their other products?

Comment: Sorry, I know this should be in chat. Amazon.co.uk has New-Skin Liquid Bandage.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.  I haven't tried that.  I'd imagine that it wouldn't be strong enough to hold the duct tape on though...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43694/discussion-between-dorothy-and-max-williams).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is going to be sweat, waterproof duct tape will prevent sweat evaporating and will cause the tape to un-stick.

As the NHS states:

> There is limited evidence to support the effectiveness of using duct
>   tape to treat warts. However, side effects of this type of treatment
>   are rare, although the skin can become irritated.

I suggest using the other methods: Salicylic acid or Cryotherapy

Comment: Thanks @JJosaur.  I used the duct tape to very successfully treat a verucca so thought I'd give it a try with the wart.  I've tried salocyclic acid and also had the doctor try and freeze it off (i asked them to give it the maximum length of spraying, ten seconds IIRC), but it keeps coming back, the bugger.  You're right about sweat making it fall off though.